# preg_match help

Tags: php

I want to extract some phone numbers that are in a local text file on my hard drive. I'm thinking that I can use preg_match for this. I've got the following that manages to pull the first phone number then stops. Do I need a loop or what am I missing to get all of the phone numbers? I'm not even sure that my regex is correct. The phone numbers are all in the format: xxx-xxx-xxxx

```
$file=file_get_contents('1.txt');
preg_match('/([0-9]){3}-([0-9]){3}-([0-9]){4}/', $file, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: The entire website is about "help". Please make your question title useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice a similar function named [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)?

Comment: Yes sir, works well, thanks again. I can accept this answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @jackD: You're kidding, right? Instead of squaring up to me on the internet (lol), try to see my comment for what it is: a hint that you should read the manual for _every_ function you use, if you do not know what it does. This is said here to _help_ you.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'd have to say 1/2 kidding. The point is well taken Tomalak. I'm just tired... Too much coding